# Does Amazon S3 have folders?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

[This documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/walkthrough1.html) says that quote:

> create a bucket with folders

IIUC S3 does not have folders.  We can simulate folders by including the folder name in the object key like this:

```
folder1/key1.json
folder1/key2.json
```

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are correct - there are no real folders, they are just simulated based on the object key having the slash in its name.